# Comparing bornologies for domination/escaping

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

Consider the following [bornologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornology) $\mathbb{D},\mathbb{E}$ on the set $\mathcal{N}$ of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$:

- $\mathbb{D}=\{A: \exists f\in\mathcal{N}\forall g\in A\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\forall n>m(f(n)>g(n))\}$. (**Dominatable** sets)
- $\mathbb{E}=\{A: \exists f\in\mathcal{N}\forall g\in A\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\exists n>m(f(n)>g(n))\}$. (**Escapable** sets)

My question is when, set-theoretically speaking, these yield equivalent (= "bornomorphic") bounded structures on $\mathcal{N}$:

> Is it consistent that $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{d}$ but there is *not* a bijection $i:\mathcal{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{N}$ such that the $i$-image of each set in $\mathbb{D}$ is in $\mathbb{E}$ and the $i$-preimage of each set in $\mathbb{E}$ is in $\mathbb{D}$?

Here $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{d}$ are the cardinal characteristics corresponding to escaping(/**b**ounding) and domination: the minimal cardinalities of sets of functions not dominated/escaped by any individual function, respectively. Clearly in order for $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{E}$ to be equivalent as bornologies we need $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{d}$; I'm curious whether any additional information is captured by considering the bornological structure present.

Comment: An interesting variation: do such "bornological equivalences" exist assuming CH?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I think $\mathsf{CH}$ lets you perform a sort of "greedy algorithm" to construct a bornomorphism (countable sets being unproblematic in any way).

Comment: Maybe more information is captured by considering Borel isomorphisms?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I'd be interested in that follow-up question; would you like to ask it? (I feel a bit hesitant to "double-dip" reputation from the same basic idea.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais [I gave in to temptation.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448818/comparing-bornologies-for-cardinal-characteristics-via-borel-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{d}$ is equivalent to the existence of a $<^\ast$-increasing sequence $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{d}}$ which is cofinal in $(\mathcal{N},{<^\ast})$, where $f <^\ast g \iff \exists n\,\forall m \geq n\,{f(m) < g(m)}$.

For $\alpha<\mathfrak{d}$, let
$$\begin{aligned}
 D_\alpha &= \{ g \in \mathcal{N} \mid g <^\ast f_\alpha \}, &
 E_\alpha &= \{ g \in \mathcal{N} \mid f_\alpha \not<^\ast g \}.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $D$ is dominatable iff $D \subseteq D_\alpha$ for some $\alpha < \mathfrak{d}$, and that $E$ is escapable iff $E \subseteq E_\alpha$ for some $\alpha < \mathfrak{d}$.

With some thinning of the cofinal sequence $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{d}}$ if necessary, we can make sure that for every $\alpha < \mathfrak{d}$ the sets
$$\begin{aligned}
&D_\alpha \setminus {\textstyle\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} D_\beta}, &
&E_\alpha \setminus {\textstyle\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} E_\beta},
\end{aligned}$$
each have size $\mathfrak{c}$. Working level-by-level, we can construct a bijection $\mathcal{N} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{N}$ which restricts to a bijection $D_\alpha \leftrightarrow E_\alpha$ for every $\alpha<\mathfrak{d}$. Such a bijection shows that the two bornologies are equivalent.